# Check modified time of files and directories recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a script that checks and compares the modified time of a directory and files.  How can I do this so that recursive files and directories will also get checked.  Currently, only the root directory is checked.

```
import os
import time, stat

source_dir  = 'C:/Mydirectory'

# current time - last modified time
dtime = time.time() - os.stat(source_dir)[stat.ST_MTIME]

if dtime <= 30:   # 30 seconds
    print("Found modification in last 30 seconds.")
    run_here()
```

Comment: It seems my answer is the only one that is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) to process every entry in the directory tree.

```
with os.scandir(source_dir) as it:
  for entry in it:
    dtime = time.time() - entry.stat()[stat.ST_MTIME]
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) can help you iterate through the source dir. It can be done like this

```
import os
import time, stat

source_dir  = 'C:/Mydirectory'

for currentdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):

   for file in files:
      currentfile = os.path.join(currentpath, file)
      # current time - last modified time
      dtime = time.time() - os.stat(currentfile )[stat.ST_MTIME]

      if dtime <= 30:   # 30 seconds
          print("Found modification in last 30 seconds for file =>", currentfile)

   for folder in dirs:
      currentfolder = os.path.join(currentpath, folder)
      # current time - last modified time
      dtime = time.time() - os.stat(currentfolder)[stat.ST_MTIME]

      if dtime <= 30:   # 30 seconds
          print("Found modification in last 30 seconds for folder =>", currentfolder )
```

Answer (score 0):

Following, are simple methods to retrieve files in the current directory, using `os` and the `lsitdir()` function in Python 3.

```
import os
import time, stat

source_dir  = 'C:/Mydirectory'

# current time - last modified time
with os.listdir(source_dir) as it:
  for entry in it:
    dtime = time.time() - os.stat(entry.path)[stat.ST_MTIME]

if dtime <= 30:   # 30 seconds
    print("Found modification in last 30 seconds.")
    run_here()
```

Comment: This gives me an AttributeError: '*_*enter*_* for 'with os.listdir(source_dir) as it:'

Answer (score 0):

You should use `listdir` to find out and go through all the files and directories in your current directory. I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
import os
import time, stat

source_dir  = 'C:/Mydirectory'

def recursiveScan(dir):
    # current time - last modified time
    dtime = time.time() - os.stat(dir)[stat.ST_MTIME]
    if dtime <= 30:   # 30 seconds
        print("Found {} was modified in last 30 seconds.".format(dir))
        run_here()
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        try:
            recursiveScan(dir+"/"+file)
        except:
            continue

recursiveScan(source_dir)
```